# Assigned fetched resource image url returns get error with local path

Tags: javascript, url, fetch, fetch-api

When attempting to assign the returned URL field of a JSON object retrieved from the [NASA](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap201014.html) [APOD](https://github.com/nasa/apod-api) API to a HTMLImageElement src property I receive a GET error. The error shows that the GET request appends a local file path before the external URL path.

Console logged as:

```
GET file:///C:/Users/username/OneDrive/Documents/Coding/NASA-POTD/Image%20of%20the%20day%20https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2010/RhoAntares_Abolfath_1080.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

You can inspect my code below.

```
const sourceImg = document.getElementById('img');

const DATE = '&date=2020-10-14'

const RESOURCE = `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=hDhaSTsRNtw5sjymgxbwQDAfLGb7mDXcgxctq7xI${DATE}`;

fetch(RESOURCE)
.then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) { 
        errorReturned = true;
        throw new Error('error')
    };
    let reqBody = res.text();
    return reqBody
})
.then(reqBody => {
    let receivedRes = JSON.parse(reqBody)

    sourceImg.src = `Image of the day ${'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2010/RhoAntares_Abolfath_1080.jpg'}`
})
```

If anyone could help with the semantics of my question, I am a noob who doens't quite know how to word the question to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By a serendiptous rewrite of the code I realize that you cannot have the HTMLImageElement.src property be set to a template literal.

Fixed with this:

```
sourceImg.src = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2010/RhoAntares_Abolfath_1080.jpg';
```